# Pause and Resume Job Execution Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

Have the same question asked here -

[Spring batch pause/resume vs stop/restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961698/spring-batch-pause-resume-vs-stop-restart)

I checked BatchStatus enum in spring, there is no status PAUSED available, it is only provided as use case without details here -

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.1.x/cases/pause.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring batch pause/resume vs stop/restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961698/spring-batch-pause-resume-vs-stop-restart)

Answer (score 1):

use job operator for this, it is the basic interface which provides functionalities such as stop , restart , getStatus

```
public interface JobOperator {

List<Long> getExecutions(long instanceId) throws NoSuchJobInstanceException;

List<Long> getJobInstances(String jobName, int start, int count)
      throws NoSuchJobException;

Set<Long> getRunningExecutions(String jobName) throws NoSuchJobException;

String getParameters(long executionId) throws NoSuchJobExecutionException;

Long start(String jobName, String parameters)
      throws NoSuchJobException, JobInstanceAlreadyExistsException;

Long restart(long executionId)
      throws JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, NoSuchJobExecutionException,
              NoSuchJobException, JobRestartException;

Long startNextInstance(String jobName)
      throws NoSuchJobException, JobParametersNotFoundException, JobRestartException,
             JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException;

boolean stop(long executionId)
      throws NoSuchJobExecutionException, JobExecutionNotRunningException;

String getSummary(long executionId) throws NoSuchJobExecutionException;

Map<Long, String> getStepExecutionSummaries(long executionId)
      throws NoSuchJobExecutionException;

Set<String> getJobNames();

}
```

Here is an example for that

[JOB_OPERATOR EXAMPLE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html)